# How do I open another html page in the same tab using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a code in which I try to open another page, but when I click on the button nothing happens, the console is also empty, how can I solve this or maybe I have an error somewhere?
P.S. I use Jquery
HTML, JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Biograpy</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap-grid.min.css">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">BIOGRAHPY</a>
            <div class="navbar-wrap">
                <ul class="navbar-menu">
                    <li><button class="button1">About me</button></li>
                    <li><button class="button2">Portfolio</button></li>
                    <li><button class="button3">Place of study</button></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" class="contacts">Contacts</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="text1" id="option">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="portfolio" id="option2">Тест2</div> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="C:\Users\adeni\OneDrive\Desktop\site\jquery-3.6.1.min.js">
        $('button1').click(function(){
            window.location = $(this).find('.About_me').html();
        })  
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #000;
    min-width: 320px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: auto;
}
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
.navbar .container {
    height: inherit;
    display: flex;;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.navbar-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.navbar-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-menu li button {
    border-radius: 60px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    opacity: .6;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar-menu li button:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.text1 {
    display: none;
}
.visible_block {
    display: flex;
}
.navbar-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.contacts {
    margin-left: 25px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: lightcoral;
    border-radius: 90px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(255, 127, 80, .2);
    transition: all .7s ease-in;
}
.contacts:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 9px 9px rgba(255, 127, 80, .5);
    transform: scale(1.050);
    color: #000;
}
.navbar-brand {
    font-weight: : 700;
    font-size: 26px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    transition: all .7s ease-out;
}
.navbar-brand:hover {
    color: lightcoral;
}
```

I tried to change the names that apply to classes, or to set types and ids at all, but it also did not lead to anything.

Comment: `$('button1')` looks for `<button1>` which you don't have - change to `$('.button1')` - note the prefix "."` - jquery selectors work the same as css (mostly):  `.` for a class

Comment: `window.location = $(this).find('.About_me').html()` your `<button class=button1` does not have any child elements, let alone one with class=About_me, there's also no other class=About_me in your provided code, so it still won't "do anything".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing some basic points:

**First** Your reference tag to jQuery is wrong. Better to add jQuery or other js files whith relative address. For example put the file in the same folder as your html file and do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src ="jquery-3.6.1.min.js">
</script>
```

**Second** add another `script` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.button1').click(function(){
            window.location.href = $(this).find('.About_me').html();
        }) 
</script>
```

**Third** Start addressing button one with a `.` (as the code above) while you are using it's class.

**Fourth** There is not tag with the class `About_me` so the code will not work. Also notice that the tag should contain the address of the page

**Fifth** if you want to redirect the page you should use  `window.location.href` and not `window.location`. If you want to open a new window use  `window.open([address here])`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming tour pages are `www.misite.net/about.html`, `www.misite.net/portfolio.html`, and so on:

```js
$('.navbar-menu').find('button').on('click', function() {
  let page = $(this).data('page');
  let urlToOpen = window.location.origin + '/' + page;
  console.log(urlToOpen);
  window.location.replace(urlToOpen);
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #000;
  min-width: 320px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: auto;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.navbar .container {
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  ;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-menu li button {
  border-radius: 60px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  opacity: .6;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-menu li button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text1 {
  display: none;
}

.visible_block {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.contacts {
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  border-radius: 90px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(255, 127, 80, .2);
  transition: all .7s ease-in;
}

.contacts:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 9px 9px rgba(255, 127, 80, .5);
  transform: scale(1.050);
  color: #000;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-weight: : 700;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  transition: all .7s ease-out;
}

.navbar-brand:hover {
  color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">BIOGRAHPY</a>
    <div class="navbar-wrap">
      <ul class="navbar-menu">
        <li><button class="button1" data-page="about.html">About me</button></li>
        <li><button class="button2" data-page="portfolio.html">Portfolio</button></li>
        <li><button class="button3" data-page="pts.html">Place of study</button></li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#" class="contacts">Contacts</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="text1" id="option">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```